# for the present

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Heritage is concerned with the ways in which very selective
> material artefacts, mythologies, memories and traditions
> become resources for the present.

What's the meaning of 'for the present'? (in the context above).

the present means existing people or 'for the present' means 'for the time being'?

Comment: The phrase can be interpreted both ways but would generally be understood to mean for the present generation.

Comment: Thx. in the context above, the phrase menas for the present generation?

Comment: I see no reason to single out "the present **generation**" as the "missing noun". The usage ***the present*** here looks to me like a form of [***metonymy***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) ("the present **time**" represents / stands in for "anything / anybody in existence now, that might make use of things created / done / thought in the past". These days, that's as likely to be today's ***computers & AI systems*** using the resources of the past, not just the current generation of humans.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thx. the metonymy you mentioned may be 'for the present generation' because heritage is something the formergeneration passes over to the next generation. Also, if sth becomes resources, for whom the resources should be?

Comment: resources for Google's AI? Or maybe resources for the (aliens? god(s)?) running the simulation we think of as "reality"? I dunno - I'm just saying there's no reason to try and settle on a *specific* noun to identify "**something / someone** in existence **now**" that might use the specified "resources".